# Facebook ads insight api - get audience infos

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to retrieve the data that is accessible in the "Ads Manager" about the age and gender of an audience by facebook-graph-api?
[image]

That is my actual code to retrieve data about a campaign, ad set or ad:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/<ad account>|<campaign>|<ad set>|<ad>/insights?access_token=<access_token>
```

But as far as i could see there are no infos about age and gender included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found a solution `breakdowns=["age","gender"]`!

Encoded as url:

```
.../insights?breakdowns=%5B%22age%22%2C%22gender%22%5D&access_token=<access_token>
```

Comment: Hey, do you know how to get the same for custom audiences?

Comment: Here's my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42083786/fetching-facebook-custom-audience-insights-after-creating-and-adding-users-using